# Xamarin - How to trigger an animation using a MessagingCenter

Tags: c#, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I have a `ContentView` that is subscribed to a `MessagingCenter` message from a ViewModel (In order to maintain the mvvm pattern by not coupling the view to the viewModel).
When the message is received by the `ContentView` I wanted it to perform an animation to make a swipe view visible as follows:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SideMenuViewModel>(this, "IsMenuOpen", async (sender) =>
{
    if (sender.IsMenuOpen)
    {
        MainSwipeView.Open(OpenSwipeItem.RightItems);
        await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);
    }
    else
    {
        MainSwipeView.Close();
        await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);
    }
});
```

This animation is the same as the one that I have in other event listeners on the same file and it works fine. However, in the `MessagingCenter` the chain of execution works fine and it calls the animation method but no animation happens.

Could this potentially be a threading issue? I've tried both `await` and `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` but neither worked.

Comment: How to you actually send the data from messaging center, add that as well

Comment: @Blu That's not really relevant as the Subscriber works perfectly fine in getting the message, but it's just that the animation methods don't work when they get called.

Comment: Could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something this, hope it may be helpful.

> MessagingCenter for SEND

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SideMenuViewModel:IsMenuOpen", IsMenuOpen);  //IsMenuOpen - is the bool value for your situation
```

> MessagingCenter for SUBSCRIBE

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SideMenuViewModel, bool>(this, "SideMenuViewModel:IsMenuOpen", (sender, IsMenuOpen) =>
     {
        if (IsMenuOpen)
        {
            MainSwipeView.Open(OpenSwipeItem.RightItems);
            await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);
        }
        else
        {
            MainSwipeView.Close();
            await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);
        }
});
```

Your bool value will be fetched in the `IsMenuOpen` parameter of subscribe. Which will have scope locally within only MessagingCenter.

Let me know if it works fine or not...

Comment: Those are useful tips for MessagingCenter, but they don't actually help with the problem... My issue was that the MessagingCenter works as expected and the animation methods get called, but no animation happens even though the ScaleToY method is called.

Comment: i just saw it, in your `if else` both have same operations `wipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);`

Comment: Yeah they're the same operation, but that's not the problem, the issue is no matter which part of the `if else` happens, NO animation occurs at all

Answer (score 0):

`await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1, 300, Easing.SinOut);`

The `ScaleTo` method obtains the current `Scale` property value (default value of 1) for the start of the animation, and then scales from that value to its first argument,`1` seems to mean no change, and you try to change it to a value that is not `1`.

like:

```
await SwipeContent.ScaleYTo(1.5, 300, Easing.SinOut);
```